# docker-compose mongo unable to authenticate after initialising with custom admin password

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

This is my docker-compose file

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: "3.1"
services:
  mongo1:
    container_name: mongo1
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGO_USER}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGO_PASS}
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: ${MONGO_DB_NAME}
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
      - 28017:28017
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - volume-mongo:/data/db
      - ./mongo/init-mongo-js.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-mongo.sh:ro
    command: ['--auth', '--wiredTigerCacheSizeGB=1']
    networks:
      - mongo-network
  # mongo-express:
  #   container_name: mongo-express
  #   image: mongo-express
  #   restart: always
  #   ports:
  #     - '8081:8081'
  #   env_file:
  #     - .env
  #   environment:
  #     - ME_CONFIG_OPTIONS_EDITORTHEME=ambiance
  #     - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME=${MONGO_USER}
  #     - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD=${MONGO_PASS}
  #     - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN=true
  #     - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_AUTH_DATABASE=admin
  #     - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongo1
  #     - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=${MONGO_USER}
  #     - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=${MONGO_PASS}
  #   depends_on:
  #     - mongo1
  #   networks:
  #     - mongo-network
volumes:
  volume-mongo:
    driver: local

networks:
  mongo-network:
    driver: bridge
```

**init-mongo-js.sh**

```
mongo <<EOF
use ${MONGO_DB_NAME}
db.createCollection("users")
db.users.insert({"name": "john"})
EOF
```

## running docker

I have cleared my volumes, containers, networks and run this fresh

```
docker volume prune
docker network prune
docker container prune
docker-compose up
```

***It says it successfully creates user***

```
mongo1    | Successfully added user: {
mongo1    |     "user" : "MYNEWUSERNAME",
mongo1    |     "roles" : [
mongo1    |             {
mongo1    |                     "role" : "root",
mongo1    |                     "db" : "admin"
mongo1    |             }
mongo1    |     ]
mongo1    | }
```

When I try to login via sh, it fails

```
docker exec -it mongo1 mongo admin -u MYNEWUSERNAME -p password
```

> MongoDB shell version v4.4.3
> connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/admin?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
> Error: Authentication failed. :
> connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
> @(connect):2:6
> exception: connect failed
> exiting with code 1

Comment: https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/174, Read the whole thread, check if you case is already there.

Comment: No, because I added:
mongo <<EOF
use admin
db.createUser(
    {
        user: "${MONGO_USER}",
        pwd: "${MONGO_PASS}",
        roles:[
            {
                role: "admin",
                db:   "${MONGO_DB_NAME}"
            }
        ]
    }
);

EOF

Comment: Mind elaborating?

Comment: There are several causes that result with the same error. Each requires own fix.

Comment: If i remove my sh file i can login. The problem is adding it to create a db then prevents authentication.

Comment: Now it makes more sense. I want to reproduce it, what is the "MYNEWUSERNAME" in the logs? is it `${MONGO_USER}` from the docker-compose?  what is `${MONGO_DB_NAME}` in your shell script? What `docker exec mongo1 /bin/sh -c 'ls -al docker /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d' ` returns? I expect 1 file.

Comment: @AlexBlex Lets say for your question: It is: MONGO_DB_NAME=somedb  MONGO_USER=MYNEWUSERNAME  MONGO_PASS=password

Comment: sorry mate, it is for **your** question. I am just clarifying missing and confusing bits

Comment: I couldn't reproduce. I copy-pasted everything from the question, started `docker-compose up` and successfully logged in: `mongo1    | 2021-01-28T16:44:27.095+0000 I  ACCESS   [conn1] Successfully authenticated as principal MYNEWUSERNAME on admin from client 127.0.0.1:53250`

Comment: Are you sure you read the whole thread on github and checked all possible causes of the error mentioned there?

Comment: @AlexBlex Thanks for trying it. Thats interesting it works. I wonder if its because I'm using windows 10. Will experiment more.

Comment: I have resolved my problem with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66006565/how-to-write-bash-script-for-init-mongo-shro-to-add-admin-user-and-run-an-initi/66007221#66007221

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write bash script for init-mongo.sh:ro to add admin user and run an initialisation script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66006565/how-to-write-bash-script-for-init-mongo-shro-to-add-admin-user-and-run-an-initi)

Comment: @AlexBlex Yes, I can't answer my own resolution yet. Will do once time period has passed.

Comment: Hey Steve, sorry for the confusion, the commend is automatically generated when a question is marked as a duplicate.