# How to write bash script for init-mongo.sh:ro to add admin user and run an initialisation script

Tags: mongodb, bash, docker, docker-compose

My docker compose of mongo fails to authenticate when I add a docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-mongo.sh:ro file

**docker-compose**

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  mongo1:
    container_name: mongo1
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGO_USER}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGO_PASS}
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: ${MONGO_DB_NAME}
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
      - 28017:28017
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - volume-mongo:/data/db
      - ./mongo/init-mongo-js.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-mongo.sh:ro
    command: ['--auth', '--wiredTigerCacheSizeGB=1']
    networks:
      - mongo-network
  # mongo-express:
  #   container_name: mongo-express
  #   image: mongo-express
  #   restart: always
  #   ports:
  #     - '8081:8081'
  #   env_file:
  #     - .env
  #   environment:
  #     - ME_CONFIG_OPTIONS_EDITORTHEME=ambiance
  #     - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME=${MONGO_USER}
  #     - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD=${MONGO_PASS}
  #     - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN=true
  #     - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_AUTH_DATABASE=admin
  #     - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongo1
  #     - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=${MONGO_USER}
  #     - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=${MONGO_PASS}
  #   depends_on:
  #     - mongo1
  #   networks:
  #     - mongo-network
volumes:
  volume-mongo:
    driver: local

networks:
  mongo-network:
    driver: bridge
```

**.env**

```
MONGO_DB_NAME=DBX
MONGO_USER=MYNEWUSERNAME
MONGO_PASS=somesecret
# Mongo host
```

Attempting to login fails

```
docker exec -it mongo1 mongo admin -u MYNEWUSERNAME -p somesecret
```

When I remove the reference to the init-mongo.sh:ro- file then it works but then I don't get to run my initialisation script.

I have been referred to this article:
https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/174

I'm assuming the reason it fails is because my bash file - init-mongo.sh:ro is overwriting this file:

```
if [ "$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME" ] && [ "$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD" ]; then 
  rootAuthDatabase='admin' 

  "${mongo[@]}" "$rootAuthDatabase" <<-EOJS 
    db.createUser({ 
      user: $(_js_escape "$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME"), 
      pwd: $(_js_escape "$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD"), 
      roles: [ { role: 'root', db: $(_js_escape "$rootAuthDatabase") } ] 
    }) 
  EOJS 
fi
```

If that theory is correct then including it into my script with my additional changes seems like a good solution. The only problem is in my vscode, with shell-format extension, the colour coding of this code combination doesn't look right so I suspect its wrong.

**init-mongo.sh:ro**
Attempting to combine the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
# set -e causes the whole script to exit when a command fails, so the script can't silently fail and startup mongo.

if [ "$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME" ] && [ "$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD" ]; then 
  rootAuthDatabase='admin' 

  "${mongo[@]}" "$rootAuthDatabase" <<-EOJS 
    db.createUser({ 
      user: $(_js_escape "$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME"), 
      pwd: $(_js_escape "$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD"), 
      roles: [ { role: 'root', db: $(_js_escape "$rootAuthDatabase") } ] 
    }) 
  EOJS 
fi 

mongo <<EOF
use ${MONGO_DB_NAME}
db.createCollection("users")
db.users.insert({"name": "mike"})
EOF
```

Any help in fixing this bash script appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Steve, there is no need to theorise, just check what `docker exec mongo1 /bin/sh -c 'ls -al docker /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d'`  returns with and without your script. I already asked you in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65936051/docker-compose-mongo-unable-to-authenticate-after-initialising-with-custom-admin but got no answer.  There is no need to merge files anyway. Mongo process all files in this directory in alphabetical order. If names clash just rename your file.

Comment: @AlexBlex thanks Alex. I have found a fix which I'm going to reply now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have experimented and removed the reference in the docker-compose file

```
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGO_USER}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGO_PASS}
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: ${MONGO_DB_NAME}
```

and instead create the admin user directly in the init file.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

mongosh <<EOF
use admin 
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "${MONGO_USER}",
    pwd: "${MONGO_PASS}",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }, "readWriteAnyDatabase" ]
  }
)

use ${MONGO_DB_NAME}
db.createCollection("users")
db.users.insert({"name": "john"})
EOF
```

**UPDATED - March 2023**

In addition there are 2 other problems I had - which I have now updated as below:
I was having problems authenticating when referring back to this script

1. It was because the new mongo connection uses 'mongosh' not 'mongo'
   so script is now mongosh <<EOF - NOT mongo <<EOF
2. I had to clear my docker volume  (because the init script) only runs when the volume has not already been created - ie docker volume rm volume-mongo OR docker volume prune

Following steps to rerun - and test authentication was created for mongo

4. docker container rm mongo1
5. docker-compose up
6. docker exec -it mongo1 mongosh admin -u MONGO_USER -p MONGO_PASS